# SEO value in links from same hosting account

Tags: seo, links

I have a number of websites on my hosting account - all of these belong to me.

One of these websites is a website development consultancy / agency - assume this is my day job.

The other websites are unrelated and cater for different niches (one's a job site, one's a coffee review site etc.).

All of my niche websites include a "website developed by... " link in the footer - these all point to my website development consultancy website (because I built those websites).

I know people go to great lengths to maintain Private Blog Networks (PBNs) -
 hosting their sites via different providers, using separate log in information, different themes etc. and PBNs are against Google's ToS.

**My question(s)**

1. Would the niche website links to my main website have any SEO value
2. Could these links be considered as a PBN attempt?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you put "nofollow" links to all of the websites you have designed. This will be useful especially if these websites are not in topical relevance to your website (which I assume they are; unless they're from any website design-related blogs). I don't think this will be considered a PBN attempt as long as you have properly indicated that "this website is designed by" or "website design by" or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

We have answered this same question in a variety of ways.

The up-shot is this. If you are linking in a natural way that any webmaster would, generally, this would not be a problem. However, there are limits that you should be aware of.

You are creating a link scheme and technically speaking, this is against Google guidelines. There is a certain amount of tolerance of course, however, who can say where the line is drawn?

This answer addresses buying links, however, it does address how Google looks at link schemes.

[Does Google punish pyramid linking and does reverse negative SEO exist?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/91908/does-google-punish-pyramid-linking-and-does-reverse-negative-seo-exist/91921#91921)

This answer speaks to links Google does not like and defines white-hat versus black-hat links.

[Is link building a white hat SEO activity?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/18643/is-link-building-a-white-hat-seo-activity/86906#86906)

This answer also talks about how Google views links.

[If i have multiple links to the same site on a page is it better to have only 1 passing link equity or all passing link equity?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/89726/if-i-have-multiple-links-to-the-same-site-on-a-page-is-it-better-to-have-only-1/89735#89735)

This is a short answer with a cautionary example of exactly what you are doing.

[Drop in rankings after removing sitewide backlinks](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/59077/drop-in-rankings-after-removing-sitewide-backlinks/59097#59097)

This answer talks about what a toxic link is.

[What is a toxic link?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/83825/what-is-a-toxic-link/83835#83835)

This is a small example of answers written that should well educate you on when a link is good or bad.

In your case, if you are talking about just a few sites, a simple review of your process is in order, however, you may find that you are flying under the radar. Be that as it may, you are creating links from low value sites to one of slightly more value. The question is this. What value are you adding? Probably not much. So why are you doing it? It would be far better to link your sites content in a higher value way. Consider that as a strategy.